# Is there any way to filter a "only" single value without two subqueries?

Tags: sql, subquery, user-input, crm, metabase

So my database has transactions from users on different stores and i would like to obtain ONLY the users that purchased on a single store , not multiple. I am currently working with these two subqueries but is a lil slow to load.

```
and user.id in (
select
u.id
from usertable u
join ordertable o on o.user_id=u.id
join storetable s on s.id = o.store_id
where s.id *(store id)* = #### and o.created at time zone 'Country/City' < '2020-11-01'
and o.status not ilike 'canceled%'
and o.order_kind = 'NORMAL'
)
and u.id not in (
select
u.id
from usertable u
join ordertable o on o.user_id=u.id
join storetable s on s.id = o.store_id
where not in s.id *(store id)* (####) and o.created at time zone 'Country/City' < '2020-11-01'
and o.status not ilike 'canceled%'
and o.order_kind = 'NORMAL'
)
```

I would like to obtain the users that made a purchase on an store "####" before 11/2020 and only on that store. Any ideas to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just use aggregation and having:

```
select o.user_id
from ordertable o 
where o.created at time zone 'Country/City' < '2020-11-01' and
      o.status not ilike 'canceled%' and
      o.order_kind = 'NORMAL'
group by o.user_id
having min(o.store_id) = max(o.store_id) and
       min(o.store_id) = ####;
```

Note that neither `users` nor `stores` is needed for the query.  All the information is in `ordertable`.